# change package.json script from mac to windows

Tags: node.js, json, npm, package.json

I have a project built on MAC and the package.json script is as follows:

```
  "scripts": {
    "copyindex": "cp src/index.html build",
    "copycss": "cp src/cds.css build",
    "copyimages": "cp src/assets/images/** build/assets/images",
    "copyfonts": "cp src/fonts/** build/fonts",
    "copywc": "cp -r node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles build && cp node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js build",
    "build": "rm -rf build && mkdir build && npm run copyindex && npm run copycss && mkdir build/assets && mkdir build/assets/images && npm run copyimages && mkdir build/fonts && npm run copyfonts && npm run copywc && rollup -c",
    "start": "serve build"
  },
```

Its running fine on MAC when run **npm start**. I am using windows and it doesn't run my PC. I changed most of the commands to windows commands as below. But, it still doesn't work. Is there anything else I need to do?
I am getting the errors as command is not recognized.

```
Error: 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
  "scripts": {
    "copyindex": "copy src/index.html build",
    "copycss": "copy src/cds.css build",
    "copyfonts": "copy src/fonts/** build/fonts",
    "copywc": "copy -r node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles build && copy node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js build",
    "build": "rm -rf || rmdir /s build && mkdir build && npm run copyindex && npm run copycss && mkdir build/fonts && npm run copyfonts && npm run copywc && rollup -c",
    "start": "serve build"
  },
```

I don't want to remove the MAC commands. I want the npm script to work in both windows and MAC

Comment: "it still doesn't work" -- what doesn't work? what do you run, what do you expect, what do you get?

Comment: @ChristianFritz sorry about that. I edited the question. I am trying to run npm script using npm start. But, it doesn't run on windows. Works fine in MAC. I changed MAC commands like 'cp' to 'copy' in windows. But, still it says most of the commands are not recognized.

Comment: I don't want to remove the MAC commands. I want the npm script to work in both windows and MAC

Comment: @amar `rm` is a unix command, Windows doesn't support it. Your best bet would be using `terminal` instead of `command prompt`.

Comment: interesting problem; don't know enough about the environment `npm` scripts execute in in windows, but you'll need to detect the platform you are on and then run a different script accordingly; the "or" you are trying won't work.

Comment: @ChristianFritz,  It was working if I just run only windows commands. But, if I include MAC commands it doesn't. I want it to make it working with both platforms. I tried adding "OR||", maybe its not working. But, as far as I know, "&&" works in JSON. WHY not OR??

Comment: this has nothing to do with JSON. The commands run in the respective shells of the OSs. So `&&` and `||` need to be understood there. *BUT* even if they are, an unrecognized command won't just return a failure exit code, it raises an exception so to speak, so the OR won't even be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is that the script needs to be able to work on either Mac or Windows but doesn't know which one it is up front. Since scripting in `cmd.exe`, [the default shell used by `npm run` under windows](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script#script-shell), seems very limited and the intersection of the language understood by `cmd.exe` and `/bin/sh` (default under Mac) seems virtually empty, I think your best bet is go straight into `node` for scripting. This is an example of how this could work:

```json
{
 ...
 "build_win32": "rmdir /s && build && ...",
 "build_darwin": "rm -rf && build && ...",
 "build": "node -e \"child_process.exec(`npm run build_${os.platform()}`)\""
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. That should help. :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve that is probably by using [shx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx), which can run Unix commands on any platform.

```json
"scripts": {
  "copyindex": "shx cp src/index.html build"
  // ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  "shx": "latest"
}
```

Alternatively, you can also install individual packages that provide a single command, such as [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) for `cp`, [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) for `rm -rf`, etc. There are many of them.

Another approach would be to write these scripts in Javascript directly and run them with Node. This can be an arguably better solution when your scripts get very long. It also doesn't require you to depend on any additional package to run your scripts.

Example for `copyindex`:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fs = require("fs")
fs.copyFileSync("src/index.html", "build/index.html")
```

In your package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
  "copyindex": "node scripts/copyindex.js",
  // ...
}
```